# Can i use multiple image in background at the same time in FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to add to the background of canvas two or more image loaded in fabricjs. Can i do this?.

How i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

no fabric can only have 1 background image.